# Weird missing constraint with Logback under Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, osgi, slf4j, logback

I have a feature-based launch configuration for an Eclipse RCP product. The feature includes `ch.qos.logback.classic`, `ch.qos.logback.core` 0.9.29, and `org.slf4j.api` 1.6.1. "Validate plugins" shows this error:

> Could not find matching capability for Require-Capability: generic; filter="(&(generic=org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder)(&(version>=1.6.0)(!(version>=1.7.0))))"

even though `ch.qos.logback.classic` exports `org.slf4j.impl` 1.6.1 and I can see `StaticLoggerBinder.class` in the .jar file. What might the problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a guess: the "Require-Capability" is an OSGi 4.3 feature that corresponds to a "Provide-Capability". Logback doesn't have any such manifest header.
   https://github.com/ceki/logback/blob/master/logback-classic/pom.xml#L339